# VMWare Esx Increasing Datastore size to 8MB (Easiest way to do?)

Tags: vmware-esx, datastore

We're using Esx and we have a file server with 1TB of storage along with the regular 60GB HD for the OS.

I installed a trial of Veeam and all our Backups work great except the File Server which fails due to the TB restriction laid upon me by my short sight of using 4MB blocks.

I looked through some documentation but can't find the all-knowing answers which guide me through the process step by step.

Am I right by assuming this is the correct path?

- Log into Esx host.
- Shutdown all servers on datastore to be upgraded
- Start maintenance Mode
- Copy files manually to NAS
- Format Datastore with 8MB Blocks
- Copy files back to Esx Host
- Stop Maintenance Mode
- Reboot Servers

?

Backups are all up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, that's the way to do it, these days there's no real harm making data stores from as large a block size as possible.